# Presenting a popoverController causes status bar to disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iPad app, I'm using a popoverController to present a viewController. If I init the popover with this viewController, everything is fine.

However if I use this viewcontroller as the root controller of a navigationController, and init the popover with the navigationController, the status bar text disappears after the presentation.

I checked the `UIStatusBarHidden`, and `UIStatusBarStyle` after the presentation, they are fine, not hidden and still `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

Where is that status bar then?

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];
thisPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];

thisPopoverController.delegate = self;
settingsController.popOverController = thisPopoverController;

UIView *presentView = self.view.superview;
CGRect presentRect = [selectedCell convertRect:[selectedCell bounds] toView:presentView];
[thisPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:presentRect inView:presentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

---

I just found out that after the popover, the statusBar's alpha is set to 0...problem is there's no way to set the alpha. How does that happen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try achieving it using delegate method popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I said, I've checked the statusBar state after popover, it was not hidden. Following your suggestion I also tried setting it agian, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
settingsController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *navController =  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];
thisPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
[thisPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:<required frame> inView:<presenting View> permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks...but this is not working...and I couldn't find what's different from my code.